# Missing parent pom for Intuit's Java V3 SDK for QBO

Tags: maven, intuit-partner-platform

I'm updating to the latest version (2.3.2) of the Java V3 SDK for QBO. Following the instructions on the [IPP developer site](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/sample_code/spring_sample_app_for_quickbooksapi/0002_creating_the_app), I'm running into issues on [Step 5: Install the Dependencies](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/sample_code/spring_sample_app_for_quickbooksapi/0002_creating_the_app#section_5).

I checked out [the sample application](https://github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/QuickbooksV3API-Java) (which uses a deprecated version of the API) as listed in the documentation.  After modifying the the maven install commands listed in the documentation to match the versions in the sample application, I can install the deprecated SDK dependencies:

```
## ipp-v3-java-devkit-2.0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar
mvn install:install-file 
  -DgroupId=com.intuit.code.devkit.v3
  -DartifactId=ipp-v3-java-devkit
  -Dversion=2.0.1
  -Dpackaging=jar
  -Dfile=./QuickbooksV3API-Java/QuickbooksV3API/src/main/resources/dependencies/ipp-v3-java-devkit-2.0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar

## ipp-java-qbapihelper-1.2.0.jar
mvn install:install-file
  -DgroupId=com.intuit.code.devkit.qbhelper
  -DartifactId=ipp-java-qbapihelper
  -Dversion=1.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar
  -Dfile=./QuickbooksV3API-Java/QuickbooksV3API/src/main/resources/dependencies/ipp-java-qbapihelper-1.2.0.jar
```

At this point I am able to run the sample application and successfully connect to QBO via the API.

Now that I've downloaded the latest [IPP V3 Java SDK (24MB download)](https://intuitcorp.quickbase.com/up/bhvhx8wfg/g/re/eg/va/ipp-v3-java-devkit-1.0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar) provided in the documentation the maven install command fails:

```
## ipp-v3-java-devkit-2.3.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar
mvn install:install-file
  -DgroupId=com.intuit.code.devkit.v3
  -DartifactId=ipp-v3-java-devkit
  -Dversion=2.3.2
  -Dpackaging=jar
  -Dfile=./ipp-v3-java-devkit-2.3.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Resulting in:

```
[ERROR] The project com.intuit.code.devkit.v3:ipp-v3-java-devkit-pom:2.3.3-SNAPSHOT
        (C:\...\JavaV3SDK2.3.2\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]   Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find
          com.intuit.sb.tool.build.parent-pom:sb-parent-pom:pom:5.0.2
          in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
          repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
          interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and
          'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 4,
          column 10 -> [Help 2]
```

I've searched high and low for this parent POM artifact to no avail:  `com.intuit.sb.tool.build.parent-pom:sb-parent-pom:pom:5.0.2`

Should the latest SDK download include the parent POM or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the updated jar (`ipp-v3-java-devkit-2.3.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar`) alongside the previous one in the sample application, specifically: `QuickbooksV3API-Java\QuickbooksV3API\src\main\resources\dependencies\`

Now run maven install as before, just change the version numbers:

```
mvn install:install-file 
  -DgroupId=com.intuit.code.devkit.v3
  -DartifactId=ipp-v3-java-devkit
  -Dversion=2.3.2
  -Dpackaging=jar
  -Dfile=./QuickbooksV3API-Java/QuickbooksV3API/src/main/resources/dependencies/ipp-v3-java-devkit-2.3.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

While I'm not exactly sure why this works, I assume it has something to do with resources in paths relative to the jar itself.

Answer (score 1):

I've installed the latest devkit(2.3.2) in my local maven repo.

It looks like a caching issue. 
Please check if you have the devkit jar in the local repo.

```
<root>\.m2\repository\com\intuit\code\devkit\v3\ipp-v3-java-devkit\2.3.2
```

If you still face this issue, you can try deleting the above '2.3.2' folder and install it again.

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.intuit.code.devkit.v3 -DartifactId=ipp-v3-java-devkit -Dversion=2.3.2 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=C:\ipp-v3-java-devkit-2.3.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't see 2.3.2 in the local repository, just 2.0.1 from the initial install. I did, however, run into the issue you note when installing 2.0.1 - and can verify that deleting the jars in the local repo did solve that issue.  Fortunately, your feedback led me to a solution (I'll post it in a bit). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem weird. apperantly what it looks like is the pom.xml inside dev-ki that comes along is broken.
When you run any command in the devkit directory, it uses that pom.xml within the devkit,and fails.

what I did was I went one directory up, and then tried importing the jar again. something like this -

> mvn install:install-file  -DgroupId=com.intuit.code.devkit.v3 
>   -DartifactId=ipp-v3-java-devkit    -Dversion=2.3.2   -Dpackaging=jar   -Dfile=devkit/ipp-v3-java-devkit-jar-with-dependencies-2.4.0.jar

Interestingly this works. All of my developer jars are kept in dev-kit.
the devkit pom.xml had issues with parent module and child module, What it looks like is that the pom is just for reference, and not for execution.

-Hope this helps.